# ASP.NET C# - Textbox values not visible after being passed from another page if over certain number of characters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, window.opener

I am passing values from a pop-up page to a textbox in my parent page using javascript:

```
        function GetValue() {
        window.opener.document.getElementById('<%= Request["txtCCD"] %>').value = document.getElementById('<%=txtGetCCD.ClientID%>').value;

        window.opener.focus();
    window.close();
```

where **txtCCD** is the textbox id in parent page and **txtGetCCD** is the string of values to be passed in the pop-up page (it's a HiddenField).

Now, it all works fine IF the number of characters passed is less than roughly around 3200. But more than that, the values still do get passed to the parent page textbox BUT the values would be invisible unless I highlight the textbox!

Is there some kind of limit of textbox or does this have something to do with the way I am passing the values?

Please help!!

Comment: Is it "around 3200" or PRECISELY 3200? Did you check it using some dev tools (Firebug and such)?

Comment: Not precisely 3200...I just double checked again and if it is just above 3900 characters then the textbox values are invisible...I am not using firefox..using IE. Not too sure about checking using dev tools. What would I have to look for?

Comment: Just realised I do not have this problem in firefox...so must be an IE specific issue!

Comment: I'd look at the rendering of the page that creates the characters which populate the hidden field, and see if some unexpected mechanism is truncating them in some unusual or unexpected way.

Comment: If you're using IE9 (hope you have the latest version installed), then just hit F12 to open your dev tools almost the same as in Firebug :) There you can see everything in a nicely formatted way, debug your javascript etc.